# How to reassemble TCP chunks from websocket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, tcp, websocket

I have a websocket server written in node.js without any library. Sending messages works fine. But when i send one large file from client to server, then there is no fragmented websocket message. There is only one websocket frame, with the FIN bit set to 1. And the file is chunked in tcp pieces.
So how can i tell the "socket.on("data".." listener, give me all tcp pieces, so i can reassemble them ?
How can i separate the websocket frame from the tcp chunks ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a websocket parser. I don't think you'd expect a lot of code here, so I'll put a link to a websocket parser that I wrote for my Web Framework [simpleS](https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/).

You can try to use it for some learning purposes, but I'd suggest to use a ready framework like that I mentioned. The websocket parser is located here: https://github.com/micnic/simpleS/blob/master/lib/parsers/ws.js

Quick start:

`wsParser(limit, client)`

limit - limit in bytes of the received frame / message (zero for infinity, I use 0 for data received from the server)

client - boolean to specify if the parser is used on the client-side or the server-side

The parser may be used as a regular writable stream:

```
var parser = new wsParser(0, false);

socket.pipe(parser);

parse.on('error', function (error) {
    // handle the error
}.on('frame', function (frame) {
    // handle the frame

    /*
      The structure of a frame:
      {
        data: buffer,
        fin: boolean,
        length: int,
        masked: boolean,
        opcode: int
      }
    */
});
```

**UPDATE**

Simplified parsing process explained:

```
var buffer = new Buffer(0);  // intermediate container for data
var frame = null;            // frame object
var limit = 0;               // limit in bytes for data, may be any needed value
var message = new Buffer(0); // message data container
var state = 0;               // flag for the current parser state
var index = 0;               // read index inside the buffer data

socket.on('readable', function () {
    var data = this.read() || new Buffer(0); // get the new received data

    buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, data]);  // concat the received data

    if (state === 0) { // waiting for a new frame
        frame = {      // create the frame object
            data: new Buffer(0),
            fin: (buffer[index] & 128) === 128,
            length: buffer[index + 1] & 127,
            masked: (buffer[index + 1] & 128) === 128,
            opcode: buffer[index] & 15
        };

        // validate the frame based on the websocket protocol limitations

        // set the next step flag based on the frame properties
        if (frame.length > 125) {
            state = 1;
        } else {
            state = 2;
        }

        index += 2; // skip frame header bytes
    }

    if (state === 1) { // get extended payload length
        if (frame.length === 126) {
            // get the next 16 bits for the extended payload length

            index += 2; // skip extended payload length
        } else if (frame.length === 127) {
            // get the next 32 bits for the extended payload length

            index += 8; // skip extended payload length
        }

        state = 2;
    }

    if (state === 2) { // get the masking key
        frame.mask = buffer.slice(index, index + 4);

        index += 4; // skip masking key bytes

        state = 3;
    }

    if (state === 3) { // get payload data
        frame.data = buffer.slice(index, /* some offset */);

        // unmask frame data
        // prepare the message
        // reset parser state and frame object
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not expecting a lot of code, a little pseudo code is enough. I think I didn't explain my problem good enough. I'm already able to unmask incoming websocket frames. But in this situation, when i send a big file, i.e. a jpg image file, from client to server, the sent binary is chunked in tcp. In this chunked stream there is the websocket frame (only one with fin bit set to 1!) and i dont know how to reassemble the chunked tcp stream, because there is still the one websocket frame. So i can't just concatenate the chunked tcp in a buffer

Comment: I updated my answer, added a simplified description of what happens under the hood of my websocket parser, after reading this explanation I would recommend you to take a look at the link on github that I provided with a working prototype were all kind of aspects are taken in count.

Comment: Thank you so much, i found my fault. I forgot to concat the data -.-' Can you explain me why i don't get an 'end' event ? I'm not able to seperate between two incoming messages

Comment: @benu,  you should have a read index and the expected length of the frame, as I used in the shown example with the `index` and the `frame.length` variables, you'll have to separate the frames using these values to get the offset of the next frame (or frames), check the source in the github repo for more details.

Comment: I had a look at your example. But in this case, what happens when the connection interrupts, while sending data from client to server, i.e. when the smartphone shuts down (low battery). How could i then seperate one frame from the other ? Because, when i get incomplete data, i would not be able to jump to next frame by reading the length

Comment: in a way you could understand me better, let's imagine this situation: you received 3 frames, let's say they all have identical length, with 2 bytes frame header and 8 bytes payload data, in total each frame has 10 bytes and we received them in one tcp chunk of data of 30 bytes. We read the first 2 bytes, now we know that we have to read another 8 bytes for this frame, then we see that there is more data to read in the tcp chunk, we get the frame header again and we know that we have to read another 8 bytes and so on. This is the "algorithm" of working with the received tcp data.

Comment: But this is exactly what i cant understand. Let's say two clients, A and B, send respectively 2 frames, 2 bytes frame header and 8 bytes payload data. First frame from A, second frame from B, third frame from A and the fourth frame from B. And now let's say the third frame from A is incomplete because of an interrupted connection and only the header of the third frame arrives in the server. If I now read the next 8 byte, because of the information from the header of the third frame, then i would read the header from the fourth frame as payload data from the third frame.

Comment: Is this scenario possible ? Can it happen, that the client sends only the header, because the connection interrupted ? As I know, there is no rule how TCP chunks the data.

Comment: Yes, this scenario may happen, but in this case you can do nothing with the current connection, the client can retry by establishing another connection and send the necessary data, the currently received data is dropped.